# Как создать график для визуализации данных в JAVA?

Tags: java, графики

Нужно настроить PID- регулятор, это удобно делать по графику, вопрос в том как сделать динамический график с уставкой и текущими значениями? Возможно есть какие-то библиотеки ну или стандартные инструменты.

Answer (score 0):

Например [JFreeChart](https://www.jfree.org/).

Примеры реализация графиков можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos).